# DAHDI fails to compile in Linux Kernel 3.8.0-29-generic

Tags: compiler-errors, linux-kernel, version, asterisk

I downloaded source codes of **DAHDI 2.6.1+2.6.1** and **Linux Kernel 3.8.0-29-generic**.

When I typed `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` to install Linux kernel header I got the message as shown below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I am facing problem when I try to compile and install DAHDI on my UBUNTU Server. It displays me the messages displayed below:

```
/home/asteriskpbx/src/asterisk-complete/dahdi/2.6.1+2.6.1/linux/drivers/dahdi/wctdm.c:2604:22: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'wctdm_init_one'

/home/asteriskpbx/src/asterisk-complete/dahdi/2.6.1+2.6.1/linux/drivers/dahdi/wctdm.c:289:22: warning: 'ifaces' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]

/home/asteriskpbx/src/asterisk-complete/dahdi/2.6.1+2.6.1/linux/drivers/dahdi/wctdm.c:2592:13: warning: 'wctdm-reset_tdm' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
```

and so on...

In the end, it displays:

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3] : *** [/home/asteriskpbx/src/asterisk-complete/dahdi/2.6.1+2.6.1/linux/drivers/dahdi/wctdm.o] Error 1
make[2] : *** [_module_/home/asteriskpbx/src/asterisk-complete/dahdi/2.6.1+2.6.1/linux/drivers/dahdi] Error 2
make[2] : Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic'
make[1] : *** [modules] Error 2
make[1] : Leaving directory '/home/asteriskpbx/src/asterisk-complete/dahdi/2.6.1+2.6.1/linux'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to build from source.  I checked out the latest version of dahdi from the SVN repository.  Unfortunately the latest version is 2.6.1+2.6.1.  Go to the main site and download the latest version:

```
wget http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/dahdi-linux-complete/dahdi-linux-complete-current.tar.gzenter code here
```

Unzip and then try the "make all" command again.

Answer (score -1):

First of all error is ABOVE your log. So you not provided errors.

Most likly your issue is too old dahdi with too new kernel. Solution - use **LATEST** dahdi which is now 2.7.0.

Also you always can remove from makefile tdm card if you not need driver for it.

***If you are newbie, i HIGLY recomend you use ubuntu packages, and not do expert work(compile asterisk).***